# How to set mouseposition to 0,0 in the center of the element?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, coordinates

I'm trying to set the coordinates as shown in the top left to 0% and 0% when the cursor is on the red cross (absolute middle of element).
Going left should make the X-axis go negative. Same goes for the Y-axes when i go up. Going right/bottom should contain positive values.

As you can see in the image, the coordinates are now 50% and 50%.
A codepen to this snippet can be found @ https://codepen.io/michaelkoelewijn/pen/RVGmKN

```
let pageY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
let pageX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
let percY = ((pageY / elHeight) * 100);
let percX = ((pageX / elWidth) * 100);
```

I'm sure my formula for calculating the percentages is incorrect but i can't seem to find my answer anywhere. Does anyone have the golden answer i'm looking for?

Thanks!

[image: Javascript position]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for percentages is correct.  However `this.offsetTop` and `this.offsetLeft` are defined in the HTML specification to be measured from the top-left of the element, so the 0%, 0% coordinate is at the top-left of the box.

To do what you want, you can just subtract 50% from `percX` and `percY`:

```
let pageY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
let pageX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
let percY = ((pageY / elHeight) * 100) - 50;
let percX = ((pageX / elWidth) * 100) - 50;
```

**EDIT (if you want the range to be from -100% to 100%)**

Just multiply `percX` and `percY` by 2:

```
let pageY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
let pageX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
let percY = (((pageY / elHeight) * 100) - 50) * 2;
let percX = (((pageX / elWidth) * 100) - 50) * 2;
```

Comment: Thanks! It's that easy huh? xD
And what if i want the maximum negative to be 100% instead of 50?
Is that something thats easy to achieve?

Comment: @MichaelKoelewijn If I understand you correctly, yes :)

Comment: @MichaelKoelewijn Also very easy.  Just multiply `percX` and `percY` by 2.

Comment: Thanks Bernard. I fully understand the formula now.
It's so easy.. I don't understand why i did not figure that out myself!

Answer (score 1):

I guess:

```
let pageY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
let pageX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
let percY = (((pageY / elHeight) * 100)-50)*(-2);
let percX = (((pageX / elWidth) * 100)-50)*(2);
```

Comment: so if you are looking -100% to 100% this should work

Comment: Genius! This is indeed what i'm looking for.
Thanks a ton.